# C#/XAML WP8.1 Adding Leadbolt Ad controls

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, leadbolt

I want to add leadbolt ad controls, just like here
[leadbolt integration guide](http://help.leadbolt.com/windows-8-getting-started-sdk-integration/)

Firstly, I downloaded Leadbolt SDK for Windows Phone 8.1.
Then I created new Windows Phone app. There is a code from MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid Name="adWrapperGrid" >
    <!-- wrap your content with grid -->
    <Grid Name="yourContentGrid" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using LeadBolt.Windows8.AppAd;
```

namespace App6
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private AdController myController;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

```
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        adWrapperGrid.Loaded += adWrapperGrid_Loaded;
    }

    void adWrapperGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myController = new AdController(adWrapperGrid, "YOUR_LB_SECTION_ID");
        myController.LoadAd();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        myController.DestroyAd();
        adWrapperGrid.Loaded -= adWrapperGrid_Loaded;
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
}
```

}

So, I'm doing everything just like in the link but when I launch that app it shows me a blank screen, without Ad.

Anybody can help? Or recommend other Ad provider that works with Windows Phone 8.1 apps, and it's now a pubCenter with fill rate close to 0%?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because you're using the Windows 8 SDK on a Windows Phone 8.1 SDK which is causing incompatibility issue